# Replace ati with amd-graphics tag

Tags: discussion, tag-synonyms

At present not many people remember that AMD graphics used to be ATI sometime.

Now [amd-graphics](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/amd-graphics) is a synonym of [ati](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/ati) that seems to be wrong. It should be vice versa, so [amd-graphics](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/amd-graphics) should be displayed.

How can we do it?

Comment: I still never remember that ATI has become AMD, however of course I second the suggestion

Comment: Now you make me feel old - I grew up with ATI.

Comment: I grew up with CGA and Hercules

Comment: @thomasrutter yes, we *are* old :)