# Make ralink and mediatek tags synonyms

Tags: discussion

It looks like [ralink](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/ralink) is [mediatek](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/mediatek) now. So the tags should be synonyms.

I do not have 5 count to either of them.

Comment: I think it would be confusing to merge tags based on a company name, when questions using "ralink" will still be products with that name

Comment: Apparently it happened in 2011, and I think I still have new stuff with the Ralink brand on them. Corporate whatevers no mean that companies take over other companies on a daily basis, but many still keep the brand as it still costs money to change it. The [ati/amd-graphics](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/14236/replace-ati-with-amd-graphics-tag) thing makes more sense as they have changed it noticeably, but doing it for every company takeover would probably take a long time...